# Configuring squid to download big files on one interface and do anything else on another

Tags: squid

I have two internet connections, one with high download speeds, but it is slow for browsing. The other one is fast for browsing, but slow for downloads. I tried to set up an acl in squid to manage this but everything is still routed over just one interface.

Here is what I added to my squid.conf:

```
acl downloads url_regex -i *\.(iso|exe|rar|zip|gz|img|deb)
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.1.107 downloads
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.19
```

My browser is configured to use squid and it is working, but it is only routing traffic over 10.0.0.19.

I also tried:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.19 !downloads
```

Comment: Nevermind I got it working with FoxyProxy and a couple of regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient usage of dual connection where one is high bandwidth + high latency and the other is low bandwidth + low latency is one of the problems MPTCP is trying to address. MPTCP isn't widely deployed yet, so you should probably just stick with the solution you found.

But if anybody comes back to this question in a few years time, then MPTCP might be the proper solution at that time.